# Can we comment a div with javascript on button click

Tags: javascript, php

Can we comment a div(not hide comment) with a call of javascript on button click is it possible??? i have tried a bit but wasn't able to write the code for comment is it possible if yes than how??

Comment: **javascript** is not the same as **java**. How do you relate it with **java** tag?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot comment a DOM element. It exists. Is there!
You can hide it. Or delete it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready( function (){
   $("#myButton").click( function (){
       $("#myDiv").css({'display':'none'});
   });
});
```

The difference between `.hide()` and `.css({'display':'none'})` is that `.css({'display':'none'})` makes the object appear as if it is not there.

Answer (score 0):

You can't comment it, you can hide it which is a better choice.
Here is an example how to hide a div on click

```
<div id="myDiv">
   Bla bla bla
</div>

<button id="myButton">Click</button>

$(document).ready( function (){
   $("#myButton").click( function (){
       $("#myDiv").hide();
   });
});
```

Comment: No, because that is a DOM element. Why do you want to comment it when you can just hide it?

Comment: Thnaks for the reply... i want to hide a large div hiding it will hust create a blank space on that place...

Comment: You can fix that by doing this:

Comment: $(document).ready( function (){
   $("#myButton").click( function (){
       $("#myDiv").css({'display':'none'});
   });
});